# Activerecord: optimize select * from table query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, indexing

So I have those tables of `countries` and `regions` that contain respectively 274 and 3953 rows: not so many.

Each time I display a form with an address, I run `Country.all` and `Region.all` to have them in the dropdown to complete the address form.

Each time I get a `EXPLAIN`

```
  EXPLAIN (0.4ms)  EXPLAIN SELECT "countries".* FROM "countries" ORDER BY name ASC
EXPLAIN for: SELECT "countries".* FROM "countries"  ORDER BY name ASC
                             QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=23.83..24.52 rows=274 width=678)
   Sort Key: name
   ->  Seq Scan on countries  (cost=0.00..12.74 rows=274 width=678)
(3 rows)

  Region Load (37.8ms)  SELECT "regions".* FROM "regions" ORDER BY name ASC
  EXPLAIN (0.9ms)  EXPLAIN SELECT "regions".* FROM "regions" ORDER BY name ASC
EXPLAIN for: SELECT "regions".* FROM "regions"  ORDER BY name ASC
                            QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=323.70..333.58 rows=3953 width=48)
   Sort Key: name
   ->  Seq Scan on regions  (cost=0.00..87.53 rows=3953 width=48)
(3 rows)
```

So obviously I need to optimize those queries. But I don't know how to do that.

- Will adding an index help? As from my understanding, indexes are good to reach a specific data quickly, but here the query is `select * from <table>`
- What can I do?

Here is my migration to create the tables, in case it helps:

```
  def change
    create_table :countries do |t|
      t.string :name, :limit => 50, :null => false
      t.string :fips104, :limit => 2, :null => false
      t.string :iso2, :limit => 2, :null => false
      t.string :iso3, :limit => 3, :null => false
      t.string :ison, :limit => 4, :null => false
      t.string :internet, :limit => 2, :null => false
      t.string :capital, :limit => 25
      t.string :map_reference, :limit => 50
      t.string :nationality_singular, :limit => 35
      t.string :nationality_plural, :limit => 35
      t.string :currency, :limit => 30
      t.string :currency_code, :limit => 3
      t.integer :population
      t.string :title, :limit => 50
      t.string :comment, :limit => 255

      t.timestamps
    end

  create_table :regions do |t|
     t.references :country, :null => false
     t.string :name, :limit => 45, :null => false
     t.string :code, :limit => 8, :null => false
     t.string :adm1code, :limit => 4, :null => false
     t.float :tax_rate

     t.timestamps
  end

end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all I would limit the number of columns that I return - typically in a drop-down you would display the country name and have the ID column as a value. So in this case your `select * from countries` would become simply `select countries.name from countries`. Similarly for regions it would become `select regions.name, regions.country from regions`
In ActiveRecord you can do this thus -  Country.select("name") , Region.select("name, country"). Rails Guides Link - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields

Comment: That will help indeed. But it will save memory more than loadtime, right? I'll try it to see the results. Thanks

Comment: Given the size of your tables (274 and 3953 rows), I don't think using indexes would make that much difference. Also region and country lists don't usually change that much. Have you looked at caching your queries at the Rails level ? http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching

Comment: In fact I believe Rails does automatic caching of SQL queries as well - http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching

Comment: I'll have a look, but I agree it is weird that the query gets `EXPLAIN`ed as the tables are not too big...